# Flutter BlurhHash flickers when loaded through CachedNetworkImage

Tags: flutter

I am trying to compbine BlurHash with CachedNetworkImage to offer a nice transition when loading images from Cloud Firestore.
The problem is that most of the time the BlurHash flickers before transition to the loaded image starts.
I narrowed it down to the fact that it flickers for hashes loaded from the model object, returned from Firestore. If I hard code an blur hash the flicker doesn't occur.

```
Widget get _networkImage {
    final Duration fadeDuration = Duration(milliseconds: hasBlurhHash ? 500 : 0);
    return CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: imageURL!,
      fit: fit,
      width: width,
      height: height,
      fadeInDuration: fadeDuration,
      fadeOutDuration: fadeDuration,
      placeholder: (context, __) => hasBlurhHash ? _blurHash : _loader(context),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image(image: AssetImage("assets/img/aboutus.png")),
    );
  }

  Widget get _blurHash => BlurHash(hash: blurHash!, color: Colors.white);

  Widget _loader(BuildContext context) => ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 48.h, maxWidth: 48.h),
        child: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            strokeWidth: 4,
          ),
        ),
      );
```

The thing is that the blurHash data doesn't change so I'm not sure why it happens and/or how to solve it.

Anyone has any clue?

Comment: facing same issue !

Comment: did you manage to resolve it? @adi

Comment: @scottlee no, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem related with `CachedNetworkImage` package. When I use `blurhash` package by itself it doesn't flicker. You can use `OctoImage`. It supports blurhash as well.

And if you keep fadeInDuration smaller, you will have smooth transition.

e.g.

```dart
OctoImage(
    image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(imgUrl),
    placeholderBuilder: OctoPlaceholder.blurHash(
        imgHash,
    ),
    errorBuilder: OctoError.icon(color: Colors.grey),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    fadeOutDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
    fadeInDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 200))
```